# Angular filter on multiple array keys

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code,

```
(function (module) {

module.controller('TemplatesController', function (Template) {
    var model = this;
    model.loading = false;
    model.templates = [];
    model.attributes = [];
    model.categories = [];
    model.media = [];

    init();

    function init() {
        getTemplates();
    }

    function getTemplates() {
        model.loading = true;

        Template.types.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
            model.media = response.media;
        });
        Template.categories.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
            model.categories = response.categories;
        });
        Template.attributes.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
            model.attributes = response.attributes;
        });

        Template.templates.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
            model.templates = response.templates;
        });
            model.loading = false;
    }

    model.filteredTemplates = function () {
      return model.templates.filter(function (template) {
        return model.filterBy.indexOf(template.media_category.id) !== -1;
      });
    };

});

}(angular.module("adbuilder.dealer.templates")));
```

and html

```
<div class="filters">
                <h4 class="product-filters">Filter Category</h4>
                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default btn-block"
                           ng-repeat="category in templates.categories"
                           ng-class="{'active': category.isChecked}">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ category.id}}" ng-model="category.isChecked">
                        {{ category.name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <h4 class="product-filters">Media</h4>
                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default btn-block"
                           ng-repeat="media in templates.media"
                           ng-class="{'active': media.isChecked}">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ media.id}}" ng-model="media.isChecked">
                        {{ media.name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <h4 class="product-filters">Type</h4>
                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default btn-block"
                           ng-repeat="attribute in templates.attributes"
                           ng-class="{'active': attribute.isChecked}">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ attribute.id}}" ng-model="attribute.isChecked">
                        {{ attribute.name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

<div ng-repeat="template in filteredTemplates(templates.templates)" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 m-item">
```

I have array of checkbox, in `model.attributes`, `model.categories` and 
`model.media`. Now I want to filter `templates` to view only selected.

- `template.media_category.id` contains category id
- `template.media_type.id` contains type id
- `template.media_type_attribute_options.media_type_attribute_id` contains atribute id

How to make it works? Currently it returns nothing..

Comment: What is the problem or question?

Comment: I don't know how to make it works...

Comment: you can do something like this in filter method: var ids = [];
            angular.forEach(model.categories, function(category) {
                if (category.isChecked) {
                    ids.push(category.id);
                }
            });
            var list = [];
            if (ids.length > 0) {
                angular.forEach(model.templates, function(template) {
                    if (ids.indexOf(template.media_category.id) > -1) {
                        list.push(template);
                    }
                });
            }
            return list;

Comment: that function you are using is designed to be used with angular `filter` and you are using it incorrectly. The outer function returns a function but your use in markup would expect it to return an array